# How to retrieve data using JDBC

Tags: database, jdbc, resultset

I have been trying with the following code.

The connection is being made. But the `resultSet` is coming as empty (not null), whereas there are a couple of entries (2 fields each) in the database for the same.

It does not enter the while condition. I'm new to JDBC, please help!

My code is:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCTest123
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("oracle Connect Example.");
        Connection conn = null;
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE";
        String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        String userName = "system";
        String password = "mumpymamai";
        Statement stmt = null;
        String query = "select * from table1";  
        try
        {
            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Connected to the database");
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
            }
            conn.close();
            System.out.println("Disconnected from database");
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
oracle Connect Example.
Connected to the database
Disconnected from database
```

Comment: Format the output properly, exactly as it came(though it is obvious in this case it is generally a good practice to give the output as your terminal showed it.)

Answer (score 2):

So few suggestions. I recommend to you use `PreparedStatements` which are more faster and safer.

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next())
{
   // do some work
}
```

Second suggestion, call `close()` method in finally block, because application may crash and then your connection won't be closed. Finally block guarantees that will be always called.

Third suggestion if it doesn't work without `Exception`, probably you have empty table.