# compare records and login?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a table:

```
create table User1(Username varchar2(20) ,
 First_Name varchar2(20) ,
 Last_Name varchar2(20) , 
Password varchar2(20) ,
 Date_Of_Birth Date )
```

Also a login page with 2 fields username and password , a button "login"
Now suppose the Admin has added 4 users i.e 4 records in User1 table with their details.
saywith firstnames-U1,U2,U3,U4 each having a Username and a  password.
Now suppose User1 wants to login ,he'll have to provide his own username and password to continue..
Now help me with the JDBC code for successful login::

```
if(e.getSource()==submit)
        {
        Connection con=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
             con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:xe", "hr", "hr");
            PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement("select count(1) from User1 where Username = ? and Password = ? ");
            st.setString(1, text1.getText());
            st.setString(2, p1.getText());
             rs= st.executeQuery();
            //String t1=text1.getText();
            //String t2= p1.getText();
            if (rs.getInt(1) == 1)
                 {
                 new Rec_options();
                }
        }
        catch(SQLException ee)
        {
        System.out.println(ee);
        }
        finally
        {
         rs.close();
         con.close();
        }
        }
```

Now i'm confused what should i do inside the loop.I want is that the username and password entered in the respective fields by the user should be compared with the "Username" and "Password" columns of the table User1 ,and when any record is found with the same username and password as the one entered by the User ,login should be successful..
Please help!
Thanks

Comment: You miss WHERE condition matching entered credentials. This way you will receive all users in that loop.

Comment: use the slide bar,i used it select count(1) from user1 where username=? and password=?
used the same code you wrote in your answer.

Comment: you figured out the problem ?

Comment: What I wrote here as comment people posted as anwer later.

Comment: i edited my code,made the changes but now i'm getting 
error-unreported exception ClassNotFounfException must be caught or declared to be thrown Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")

Comment: and that too for st.close() , con.close() and ps.close() as well,same exception

Comment: Close method throws SQLException, you must catch it in finally block.

Comment: another try catch in finally block ? ok,and what about class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")-same error with this line also

Comment: done it now only one error : ClassNotFoundException must be caught
class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")

Comment: Do you know java? It is basics - if code throws exception you must either catch or rethrow it

Answer (score 0):

Once if you get resultset you can get data using getString() methode as follows.

```
if(rs.getString(1).equals(text1.getText() && rs.getString(4).equals(p1.getText())
{
  //login success
}
```

Hope [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280670/how-to-retrieve-data-using-jdbc) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 1 million users. Would you find it effective to get all the users from the database, and compare their username and password with the ones entered?

A database is used to store data, and to be able to **query** the data. You should search for a user which has the entered usename, and the entered password. If you find one, then the user is authenticated. If you don't find any, then either the username or the password is wrong.

Read the JDBC tutorial about [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). Your query should look like

```
select <what_you_need> from user where username = ? and password = ?
```

Also, if this is more than a toy application that is not meant to go to production, you should not store passwords in clear text in the database. Passwords must be cryptographically salted and hashed, preferrably with a slow algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Count the records that match your username and password values:

```
PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement("select count(1) from User1 where username = ? and password = ?");
st.setParameter(1, text1.getText());
st.setParameter(2, p1.getText());
ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery();
rs.next();
if (rs.getInt(1) == 1) {
  // login succesfull
}
rs.close();
```

Note: this is a very simplistic approach. You might want to add exception handling (e.g. make sure your JDBC resources are always closed properly. Also consider storing some hashes of passwords, rather the passwords in plain text in the database.

Comment: try / catch / finally is missing

Comment: yes, that was why I mentioned exception handling has to be added :)

Comment: cannot find symbol setParameter() //which class
cannot find symbo rs,con in finally//cause both are declared in try.

Comment: You need to declare PreparedStatement and Connection before try statement and set it to null.

Comment: i did that ,but for setParameter () ? i imported java.sql.*; but getting cannot find symbol for setParameter()

Comment: Is it PreparedStatement or Statement?

Comment: PreparedStatement.I even did import java.sql.PreparedStatement.*:,still getting same error

Comment: It is not about import, but about object. Is is cast as PreparedStatement? Show your updated code in the question.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html - setParameter is wrong, it shall be setInt, setString etc. Btw PreparedStatement shall be declared before try loop as well and closed in finally.

Answer (score 0):

```
    JTextField text1;//username
    JPasswordField p1;//password
    try{    

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:xe", "hr", "hr");

        PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from User1 WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ? ");

        st.setParameter(1, text1.getText());
        st.setParameter(2, p1.getText());

        ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery();
       if(rs.next())
         {
         //Login successfull.    
         }
       }

   catch (SQLException s){
        System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed!");
      }

   finally{
    rs.close();
    con.close();
}
```